# Show that an operator is symmetric Sturm-Liuville operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, sturm-liouville

Show that $$Ly = -y''-\frac{y'}{x} + y \quad y'(0)=0;y(1) = 0$$ defines a symetric Sturm - Liouville operator
for a suitable scalar product and determine the scalar product.

Determine eigenpairs.

So to show that the operator is symmetric we need to show that $$\langle Ly,z\rangle = \langle Lz,y\rangle$$

Hence let's start $$\langle Ly,z\rangle = \int(-y''-\frac{y'}{x} + y)z \, dx$$

On the other hand $$\langle Lz,y\rangle = \int(-z''-\frac{z'}{x} + z)y \, dx $$

Thus we will show that the operator is symmetric.

However how to show that operator is Sturm- Lioville operator?

Sturm- Liuville operator is of the form $Ly = p(x) y'' +q(x)y' +r(x)y$. Hence we can see that is Sturm Liuville right?

**Question** Could someone help please how to find a scalar product so that it will be positive? And how to find eigenpairs?

**P.s** I do not need solution to exactly this problem, but i would appretiate if someone would explain by steps how to do it

Comment: compare with the normal form $pL(y)=-(py')'+ry$, as that is self-adjoint in the standard scalar product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symmetric form is
$$
            Ly = \frac{1}{x}\left[-(xy')'+xy\right]
$$defined on $L^2_x[0,1]$ with inner product
$$
         \langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)xdx.
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
        \langle Ly,w\rangle - \langle y,Lw\rangle &= \int_{0}^{1}-(xy')'w+y(xw')'dx \\
   &=\int_{0}^{1}(-xy'w+xyw')'dx \\
   &= -xy'w+xyw'|_{0}^{1}.
\end{align}
The solutions of $Ly-y=0$ are found by solving

$$
       -y''-\frac{y'}{x}=0 \\
        \frac{y''}{y'}+\frac{1}{x}=0 \\
            \ln(xy')=C \\
             y' = \frac{C}{x} \\
              y = C\ln(x)+D
$$
So $L$ is in the limit circle case at $x=0$.
Setting $y'(0)=0$ imposes the condition $C=0$. The conditions $y'(0)=0=y(1)$ then lead to a well-posed singular Sturm-Liouville problem on $L^2_{x}[0,1]$.
The eigenvalue problem is
$$
            -(xy')'+xy = \lambda x y,\;\; y'(0)=0=y(1).
$$